# "vmstat" and "perf stat -a" show different numbers for context-switching

Tags: linux, perf, context-switch

I'm trying to understand the context-switching rate on my system (running on AWS EC2), and where the switches are coming from. Just getting the number is already confusing, as two tools that I know can output such a metric give me different results. Here's the output from vmstat:

```
$ vmstat -w 2
procs -------------------memory------------------ ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu-------
 r  b       swpd       free       buff      cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs  us sy  id wa st
 8  0          0     443888     492304    8632452    0    0     0     1    0    0  14  2  84  0  0
37  0          0     444820     492304    8632456    0    0     0    20 131602 155911  43  5  52  0  0
 8  0          0     445040     492304    8632460    0    0     0    42 131117 147812  46  4  50  0  0
13  0          0     446572     492304    8632464    0    0     0    34 129154 142260  49  4  46  0  0
```

The number is ~140k-160k/sec.

But perf tells something else:

```
$ sudo perf stat -a
 Performance counter stats for 'system wide':

    2980794.013800      cpu-clock (msec)          #   35.997 CPUs utilized
        12,335,935      context-switches          #    0.004 M/sec
         2,086,162      cpu-migrations            #    0.700 K/sec
            11,617      page-faults               #    0.004 K/sec
...
```

0.004 M/sec is apparently 4k/sec.

Why is there a disparity between the two tools? Am I misinterpreting something in either of them, or are their CS metrics somehow different?

FWIW, I've tried doing the same on a machine running a different workload, and the difference there is even twice larger.

Environment:

- AWS EC2 c5.9xlarge instance
- Amazon Linux, kernel 4.14.94-73.73.amzn1.x86_64
- The service runs on Docker 18.06.1-ce

Comment: Cannot reproduce on a bare-metal system.

Comment: Thanks for responding! So, on a bare-metal system, those counters are the same? That's good to know, at least it [probably] means that they _should_ be the same. I guess, EC2 virtualization can be to blame. I will add some more env details to the question.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot tell where discrepancy comes from. I also tested on a KVM guest system: `perf stat -a -e context-switches -I 1000` and `vmstat -w 1` are consistent there. I tested kernel 4.18 and 5.1.

Comment: Do you maybe have a version of `perf` with [the unit-scaling bug](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/61824)?  Is 4k per second consistent with 12M switches over whatever time interval you let `perf` run for?  If not, does manually calculating 12.3M / `t` seconds match up with `vmstat`?

Comment: @PeterCordes you are absolutely right! Silly me, I didn't pay attention to the absolute numbers. Indeed, if I launch it as `sudo perf stat -a -- sleep 10` and divide manually, the numbers match. Thank you!

Would you like to answer the question so that I accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some recent versions of `perf` have [a unit-scaling bug](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/61824) in the printing code.  Manually do 12.3M / wall-time and see if that's sane.  (spoiler alert: it is according to OP's comment.)

https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/1025968/

Commit 0aa802a79469 ("perf stat: Get rid of extra clock display
function") introduced the bug in mainline Linux 4.19-rc1 or so.

> Thus, `perf_stat__update_shadow_stats()` now saves scaled values of clock events
>   in msecs, instead of original nsecs. But while calculating values of
>   shadow stats we still consider clock event values in nsecs. This results
>   in a wrong shadow stat values.

Commit 57ddf09173c1 on  Mon, 17 Dec 2018 fixed it in 5.0-rc1, eventually being released with `perf` upstream version 5.0.

---

Vendor kernel trees that cherry-pick commits for their stable kernels might have the bug or have *fixed* the bug earlier.

Comment: There are two inconsistencies here. Based on the GitHub release tags, we can figure out which commit went into which kernel versions. Commit 0aa802a79469 was released in Linux 4.19-rc1, but the bug exists in 4.14 (the OP's system), so that commit could not have been the one introduced the bug. @Zulan said in the comments that the bug does not exist in 4.18, but commit 57ddf09173c1 was released in Linux 5.0-rc1.

Comment: @HadiBrais: Thanks for the research on when the commit made it into Linus's tree.  Vendor kernels probably cherry-picked those patches into *their* 4.14 kernel.